# Select control using jQuery - using value of hiddenfield

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a hidden field, which has the following markup:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$LinksOverview1$ProductView$ctrl1$ctl01$ctl00$DescriptionOfLink$QuestionDivInfo" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl1_ctl00_3_DescriptionOfLink_3_QuestionDivInfo_3" value="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl1_ctl00_3_questionMark_3" />
```

The value of my hidden field, is the same as the ID of a span i have:

```
<span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinksOverview1_ProductView_ctrl1_ctl00_3_questionMark_3" class="questionMarkLayout">(?)</span>
```

I dont know the ID of my span before the code is rendered, but I can access the value of my hidden field.

Using jQuery, I want to:

- Grap the control, with the ID of the value of my hiddenfield

So far I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>');
        $('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').val().mouseover(function (e) {
            $('<%#HintDiv.ClientID %>').show();
        });

        $('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').val().mouseleave(function (e) {
            $('<%#HintDiv.ClientID %>').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't work.

Any hints? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        alert('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>');
        var span=$("#"+$('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').val());
        $(span).mouseover(function (e) {
            $('<%#HintDiv.ClientID %>').show();
        });

        $(span).mouseleave(function (e) {
            $('<%#HintDiv.ClientID %>').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Question was not twisted, They method followed is bit twisted

Answer (score 1):

Event should be binded to control not to the value of control,

```
$('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').val().mouseover(.........
```

Should be

```
$('#'+$('#<%QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').val()).mouseover(.........
```

Your code would be

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('<% QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>');
        $('#'+ $('#<%QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').val()).mouseover(function (e) {
            $('#<%HintDiv.ClientID %>').show();
        });

        $('#'+$('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').val()).mouseleave(function (e) {
            $('#<%HintDiv.ClientID %>').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: $('<%#QuestionDivInfo.ClientID %>').mouseover() will add the handler to hidden field, not span.

Comment: Thanks @Dimitr, have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var hiddenFieldValue = $('input[id$=QuestionDivInfo_3]').attr('value');
            alert(hiddenFieldValue);
            var spanValue = $('span[id$=' + hiddenFieldValue + ']').html();
            alert(spanValue);
        });

    </script>
```

Try this....It worked for me